# Hook to Empty Object on a Bezier Curve doesn't work

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm trying to animate a Bezier Curve to achieve a rope-ish kinda animation. I found out that using the hook modifier is probably the closest to what I'm looking for, but even after selecting the vertices and adding the hook modifier to empty object, even if I moved the empty object in object mode, the curve doesn't want to stretch.

Can anyone possibly tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[image: curve and hook]

[image: curve and hook]

Here's the blend file if it might help:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/roun672kchkhef0/Boxing%20Ring.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

First unhook the hooks, keep the empty's Subdivide the curve. Go to Object mode to select the empty and the curve you want to hook it to. Then go to Edit mode, select the middle vertex of the curve and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to hook it.

Comment: That worked! I didn't know that I have to use the middle vertex of the curve to use the hook modifier, Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is an old thread, but I want to add that hooks only apply to control points in splines. Most modifiers for curves can work on control points or the curve itself.